# How to catch event of pressing TableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios, events, uitableview

I have question for you ...
I have UITableView and I want to catch event when user press the cell in order to change the color of label that I insert into UITableViewCell. The moment when user touch the cell.

1. **tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:**
2. **tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:**

functions didn't help me ...

Who have any suggestion ? Thanks a lot for help !!!

Comment: Do you mean the selection system does not satisfy you or your tableview delegate methods (i.e. `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath`) never get called ?

Comment: It get called but when user press and left finger from screen I want call some function in the moment when user press cell.

Comment: OK. Do you want to trigger a real action or just change the "selected" appearance of the cell when it's "touched" ? Be careful, because your user has to touch the cells to scroll the TableView

Comment: I Want to change color of my label that I add to cell !!!

Comment: I was asking you because the implementation depends highly on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the color of a `UILabel` inside a `UITableViewCell` when it's selected, you don't have to do any sort of event catching. You just have to change the `highlightedTextColor` property of the `UILabel`. The default is usually white.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the UITableViewCell and override the UIResponder with these:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Then you will have 2 separated events when press and when release.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the delegate of the tableView?

Did your class conform to the UITableViewDelegate protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Confirm With `UITableViewDelegate` protocol and implement the methods which you mention,

Do'nt forget to set the delegate property of your `UITableView`.

```
myTableView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at UILongPressGestureRecognizer? See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer